# magento-salesforce integration with coupons

Tags: coupon-codes, integrate

I am new to this forum but look forward to hearing from you!

We are having a company integrate Magento and Salesforce. The company is telling us that there is no way for them to have the sales price of the line item changed when a coupon is used since it's not stored at that level. They can change the total online price (stored on Opportunity level) only.

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Thanks!
Sara

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about the SalesForce side? (For Opportunity Level)
Is the company a Magento Partner and are they using Certified Developers?

Comment: I don't think they are either.

Comment: Where are they trying to make this change?

Comment: Magento side - they are saying that Magento can not figure out the end sales price per item once a coupon is displayed. For example, if the cart includes 1 apple (price $5) and 1 banana(price $10), and the coupon gave half price (so total was 7.50) then Magento can put the total online price on the opportunity but can't mark the sales price of the apple as 2.50 and the banana as 5.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefix this with ... "anything is possible, its code".

Now, how is your coupon configured? Do you have a rule saying customers get 50% off entire order?

OR do you have a coupon that says apple and banana are discounted at 50%?

Its important because depending on your use case, you may see different order totals if you add tax and/or shipping fees unto the mix.

Depending on your use case - implementation may differ and a well written solution should cover all use cases. It sounds like a provider you selected for the integration does not support all use cases or you are asking for an implementation unique to you only.

In either case, they should explain why they are saying "no" to your request.

P.S. If you run into any issues, reach out to me, I am happy to discuss the problem you are having in more detail and see if we can help (we have many SF integrations behind our belt)